# 95% Confidence interval for proportion with poisson distribution

Tags: confidence-interval

I am looking at rates of visits over time and we would like to calculate a 95% confidence interval for the increase. For example I start with 5,000 visits in year one and have 8,000 visits in year 4. I would like to calculate the 95% CI for this 60% increase. However, I am not sure how to do this for a poisson distribution. Additionally, there are individuals in this sample who have more than one visit, so there are clusters of individuals within the visits and I would also like to take this into account in my calculation. Does anyone have any suggestions? (I use R if that helps)

Comment: Roughly: For very large counts, a Wald (asymptotic) 95% CI for $\lambda$ is of the form $\hat\lambda \pm 1.96\sqrt{\hat\lambda},$ where $\hat\lambda$ is the observed count  for the domain of interest, which for you is one year. So a 95% CI for the Year 4 population mean is $(7825, 8175),$ which clearly does not contain 5000. // However, this is based on the assumption that the visits are independent, which you indicate is not so. For a more precise treatment, you'd need to know much more than you say about the probabilities of multiple related visits by one patient and about patient clusters.